How to know which package/plugin is creating somelibrary.so file in flutter?
I generated a size analysis json file(apk-code-size-analysis_01.json). I want to know which package/plugin is associated with the particular so file. Searching by these keywords/parts as in project, module, directory, scope via vscode/android studio doesn't help.
P.S. I know that libflutter.so is the Flutter Engine.

